# C++ - Mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in dllmain.obj

Tags: c++, boost, dll, nuget

I have a C++ solution with multiple projects under it, one of them is `proj1`.

1. `proj1` is a dynamic library (not static) and **I want to keep it dynamic**
2. under `proj1` I have `cpp_file` in which I want installed `boost` and `boost_locale-v143` libraries using Nuget Package Manager.
3. in `cpp_file` I added `#include <boost/locale.hpp>` and `using namespace boost::locale;` in a `cpp_file` under `proj1` and tried to compile the whole solution.
4. Now I compiled the project in Release x64 mode and it compiles well
5. I added this line of code inside a function: `boost::locale::generator gen;`
6. Now the solution doesn't compile throwing 98 errors, most of them have these two descriptions:
   `mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in dllmain.obj`
   `mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in dllmain.obj`
   To solve the problem I've followed many approaches, some of them is:

- Under `proj1` properties Going to C/C++ --> Code Generation --> Runtime Library , and tried **all** the options shown there, including `Multi-threaded (/MT)` and `Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)` and rebuild the whole project. Didn't help
- Compile the solution in VS2019 in-place of VS2022. Didn't help
- Changing the Configuration Type to `Static Library` solves the problem but it isn't an option for me as I want to get a `.dll` file

Comment: You should not mix Debug and Release so my guess is the package you got from nuget does not contain a Debug library.

Comment: @drescherjm what should I do in this situation?

Comment: Depends on the library. Can't you build the library you got off of nuget yourself? The other option is to not use the Debug configuration with your software or isolate it in a separate application and use IPC from your application (or dll) to communicate with the external process.